# ¿Es posible redirigir una ruta a otra con el URL helper de CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, .htaccess, apache2

Estoy intentando dirigir (o redirigir) una ruta mediante htaccess ya que quiero condicionar basado en la url o petición que se haga se dirija a cierto método que tengo programado.

```
mi-ruta.com // me lleva a mi método por defecto

mi-ruta.com/parametro   // <= quiero que me lleve a un método descrito
```

Intenté con la función **_remap()** de CodeIgniter, pero no logro atajar la petición o hacer que me omita el "parametro" que es escrito después de la URL base otorgandome un error 404 (obviamente no existe un controlador llamado parametro).

Con el .htaccess se puede trabajar que

```
mi-ruta.com/parametro  // redirija a
mi-ruta.com/welcome/parametro //donde welcome es mi controlador que puede manejar la petición
 //que quiero lograr y parametro es la variable que quiero analizar en dicho controlador
```

Pero no logro dar con la regla adecuada, hasta ahora monté la que me elimina el index.php de todas las url. Quisiera saber si hay alguna manera de "hacer split/explode" a cada segmento de la url y concatenar antes del "parámetro" el nombre del controlador al que quiero que redirija y hacer la redirección.

**archivo htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```